# Laravel route not working for some condition

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

i have installed laravel in wamp...here is my `routes.php` code ..

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'DirController@ShowLogin'));
```

above code works fine by displaying `login page`  but the  below code does not work...

```
Route::get('login',array('uses'=>'DirController@ShowLogin'));
```

i get an error message `public/login was not found on this server.`  anyway to fix this???

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your .htaccess file. All requests should be directed to `public/index.php`

You may want to look at the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: Maybe missing the rewrite_module on apache

Comment: @Friend Just edited my answer. The root directory of the website should be set to `/directory/public/`

Comment: @Friend Good! Please accept my answer when you'll be able.